# Project Structure using MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

As the subject says...this question is about setting up the correct structure for my project only. if you think there is a better place to ask this question then please advise.

I have a MVC 4 project using ET & repository pattern. I have DAL & UI layer at this point.

Currently i am using my DAL for data access and I created my Interfaces &  ViewModels within my Data Access Layer. i have a feeling i am doing it wrong. here is my Sample Set up.

**MY DAL LAYER (Which contains below Interface, Repo & ViewModel)**

**DAL.ViewModel**

```
Public Class ProductSummaryViewModel
    Property productGUID As Integer
    Property productName As String
End Class
```

**DAL.Interface (For Repostiory Pattern)**

```
Public Interface IProductRepository
    Property ProductIdentityID As Integer
    Property ImageMainPath As String
End Interface
```

**DAL.Products Repository**

```
Public Class productsRepository
    Implements IProductRepository   

    Private _db As websolutionsEntities = New websolutionsEntities()

Public Function AddProduct(ByVal prdSummary As ProductSummaryViewModel) As Boolean Implements IProductRepository.AddProduct

       _db.AddProduct(prdSummary )
       Return true

  End Function
```

**And here is my Controller**

```
Private ProductRepoitory As DAL.IProductRepository
    Sub New()
        Me.new(New DAL.productsRepository())
    End Sub

    Sub New(ByVal repo As DAL.IProductRepository)
        repo = ProductRepoitory 
    End Sub

Public Function AddItem(ByVal prd As DAL.ProductSummaryViewModel) As ActionResult
        Dim test as boolean = DAL.ProductRepoitory.AddItem(prd)
End Function
```

My project will grow in near future, so I want to set it up properly, however I don't want to make it too complicated as well for others and myself. Please advise with your suggestions.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to model your business logic using [commands](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [queries](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Comment: I am more interested in implementing a Business/Domain layer, but not sure how can I implement this, and on which layer i should create my interfaces & ViewModels.

Answer (score 0):

Your can divide your project like this:

CORE

- Interfaces(Ex: IProductRepository)
- Domain(Ex: Product)

DAL

- ProductRepository

MVC

- ViewModels or Models(Ex: ProductsSummaryViewModel)
- Controllers(Ex: ProductsController)

Make folders like Interfaces, Domain under CORE. You probably already have a controller folder in MVC frontend project. You also probably already have a folder called Models, just use that for ViewModels. Any thing used just for display purposes like the ViewModel classes should just exist in the front end.

Comment: Where should I create all my entities(Models for my SQL tables), and another problem I have is....if I store my viewModels under MVC layer, then my DAL methods return ViewModels...I dont really want my DAL to rely on MVC layer.

Comment: DAL should not return ViewModels they should return Models like "Product" only. You can put Models in CORE.Domain or DAL.Models. Usually, people put SERVICE layer between DATA and MVC where you can populate things like "ProductSummary" but they are not "ViewModels", they are DTO's. You can probably put those in CORE.Dto

Comment: understood, my SQL Queries are returning results from multiple tables, in other words I cant simply return the Products Objects within my DAL method, I need to return mixed columns which are defined within my ViewModels...maybe is there a way to return a Generic Type from my DAL and then use my Service Layer to populate ViewModels? you get the point?

Comment: Since you are doing custom queries then just pass ProductSummary all the way up to the MVC layer. My only suggestion is that don't consider ProductSummary a ViewModel. Just consider it a Model and define it in CORE or DAL. Once ProductSummary reaches the MVC layer just bind it to the View OR to have more flexibility may be you could make a ProductSummaryViewModel and assign all the ProductSummary variables into ProductSummaryViewModel manually(some people use a tool called automapper) in the MVC layer, this gives you the flexibility to add additional variables which may not come from database.